# Window variable declaration not working in React's index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set up Heap Analytics in my React app. I have an index.js ( no custom index.html).

In the instructions, it's saying that I should put the script in between  tag in the head. I assume that for my case, I just do it in index.js.

This is the script:

```
window.heap=window.heap||[],heap.load=function(e,t)
{window.heap.appid=e,window.heap.config=t=t||{};var r=t.forceSSL||"https:"===document.location.protocol,a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=(r?"https:":"http:")+"//cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-"+e+".js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(a,n);for(var o=function(e){return function(){heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},p=["addEventProperties","addUserProperties","clearEventProperties","identify","removeEventProperty","setEventProperties","track","unsetEventProperty"],c=0;c<p.length;c++)heap[p[c]]=o(p[c])};
heap.load(MY_APP_ID);
```

However, `heap is not defined error` comes up.

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: How is it being loaded in the browser if you aren't using html?

Comment: can you provide your index.js code?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by updating the variable declarations.

```
var heap = [];
heap.load = ... // same as above, but all instances of window.heap are replaced with just heap
window.heap = heap;
heap.load(APP_ID)
```

so I think the window variable declaration doesn't play well with React. If anyone can explain to me exactly why and how my solution works but original script doesn't, please help enlighten me.